# Does the term "in able to" exist

Tags: phrases, expressions, terminology

I came upon some texts where `in able to` is used where instead also either `to be able to` or `in order to` could have been used. `In able to` doesn't sound quite right to me. I also didn't hear it anywhere before. At first i thought `in able to` was just a mistake but now i'm not so sure anymore.  I googled it but but i didn't find any real arguments against it.

**Some Examples:**

> In addition to that, we had to wait a long time **in able to** query
> the next request (sometimes over 30 minutes).

> Previously, it has been suggested that S. aureus **in able to** survive without replication in neutrophils, > but ultimately cause lysis (Voyich et al., 2005; Kobayashi et al., 2010).

> Questioned about whether electronic surveillance of social networks by
> agencies including the NSA and GCHQ is damaging for democracy, Gadde
> pointed to Twitter's decision to sue the FBI and US Department of
> Justice in October 2014 **in able to** publish more details about
> government requests for user information.
> [Source: theguardian.com](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/jan/21/pirate-party-online-voting-4chan-government)

My question is wheter `in able to` is a existing term or not.

Comment: 'In addition to that, had we had to wait a long time in able to query the next request (sometimes over 30 minutes).' contains an(other) obvious error, so can be disregarded as a reasonable example. Your second example should obviously read 'is able to'.

Comment: The answer is simple: no. All those examples have mistakes. For example, the last one should read: so he could publish more details about government requests. And the first one is: we had to wait a long time to be able to [x]

Comment: ... I think it might actually be a transcription error, from 'in a bid to ...'

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are no convincing examples of the candidate usage given.

Comment: I cannot think of any context in which "in able to" would be correct.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the fact there are no examples answers the question.

Comment: Purely in terms of use, Google Books shows several examples of [*in able to*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20able%20to%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en); however, I can't see any example where it would not almost universally be replaced with *in **order** to*, which, in fact, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+able+to%2Cin+order+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20able%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20order%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows is *by far* the more common phrase. In other contexts, it could be ***enabled*** *to*.

Comment: I don't believe there is nearly enough common use of *in able to* to turn it from a mistake into a descriptively legitimate phrase.

Comment: The second example is certainly a typo / transcription error and should be "is able to"

Comment: The last example was apparently published by the *Guardian.* @TheDoctor, please edit your question to **link to the actual source** of the quotes (rather than any other site you found them on). Without a reliable link there is really no question: your examples may simply be transcription errors. It may be worth remarking that the *Guardian* newspaper is still affectionately known as the *Grauniad* because of the number of misprints which found their way to the final print run.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, but you're right - it sounds clunky.

I'd go with "in order to", "so as to" .. or just "to" when possible.

Comment: Hello, Dave. An answer voicing what is no more than opinion is considered unacceptable on ELU. Data or substantiating references are required.  Note that OP does not ask for workarounds, which (if it were certain that they fitted) would be too basic for ELU in any case.